# Как управлять размером изображений в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Помогите, пожалуйста, с размером картинок, выводимых с помощью `wp_get_attachment_image`

Вывожу картинку `2304х1080` через **Advanced Custom Fields**:

```
<div class="hero-img">
    <?php 
        $image = get_field('hero-img');
        $size = 'full';
        if( $image ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
        };
    ?>
</div>
```

Контейнер:

```
.hero-img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1152px;
}
```

Таким образом, выводится картинка, которая подгоняется по ширине контейнера, а высота рассчитывается исходя из пропорции оригинала. В моём случае высота выводимой картинки `540px`.

Проблемы начинаются тогда, когда я хочу управлять высотой картинки. Например, на планшете ширина контейнера картинки `768px`, высота, соответственно, `360px`.
Предположим, что на телефоне я хочу увеличить высоту картинки, и увеличиваю:

```
.hero-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 540px;
}
```

Но, на выходе получаю мыльную картинку. Проблема в том, что `wp_get_attachment_image` тянет высоту текущей версии картинки, которая подгоняется по ширине экрана (контейнера) пропорционально оригиналу, а нужно, чтобы размер рассчитывался от оригинала, учитывая необходимую мне высоту.

Можно ли это полечить?

Comment: узнай про srcset

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hero-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

или

```php
 wp_get_attachment_image_url()
```

Comment: Дело не в этом. wp_get_attachment_image подгоняет ширину исходя из экрана, а высоту исходя из пропорций оригинала. При попытке изменить высоту через css, вп вытягивает высоту текущей картинки (которая подгоняется по размеру экрана).

Comment: Тогда воспользуйтесь похожей функцией wp_get_attachment_image_url(). В ней можно задать размера выводимой картинки вне зависимости от разрешения экрана.

Comment: Размер картинки вне зависимости от размера экрана это, безусловно, интересно, но хотелось бы с зависимостью от размера экрана, но с возможностью как-то управлять высотой.